# select total sales per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, select

i have query like this and i wanted to have sum of sales per day

```
SELECT DATEPART(day,deduction_timestamp) as [day],
[fare_deduction]
FROM [dbfastsprocess].[dbo].[vClosingTransitLog]
WHERE bus_id in ('JEAST', 'MKV004', 'NWTN01')
and YEAR(deduction_timestamp) = ISNULL(2016, YEAR(deduction_timestamp))
and MONTH(deduction_timestamp) = ISNULL(10, MONTH(deduction_timestamp))
GROUP BY DATEPART(day,deduction_timestamp), fare_deduction 

with result :

day              fare_deduction
--------------------------------
1                   10.00
3                   15.00
3                   2.00
4                   10.00
10                  20.00
31                  12.00
```

and i wanted the result to be like this..

```
 day              fare_deduction
--------------------------------
1                   10.00
3                   17.00
4                   10.00
10                  20.00
31                  12.00
```

and take note that not all day have values and it only display the affected 
  day only. Can help me on these? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEPART(day,deduction_timestamp) as [day],
sum(fare_deduction) as fare_deduction
FROM [dbfastsprocess].[dbo].[vClosingTransitLog]
WHERE bus_id in ('JEAST', 'MKV004', 'NWTN01')
and YEAR(deduction_timestamp) = ISNULL(2016, YEAR(deduction_timestamp))
and MONTH(deduction_timestamp) = ISNULL(10, MONTH(deduction_timestamp))
GROUP BY DATEPART(day,deduction_timestamp)
```

Comment: try this query it will help

Comment: Please add some description to your post, script only replies are not appreciated. Highlight your query and crtl-K will align script for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `sum`, it will get your required result

```
SELECT DATEPART(day,deduction_timestamp) as [day],
SUM([fare_deduction]) [fare_deduction]
FROM [dbfastsprocess].[dbo].[vClosingTransitLog]
WHERE bus_id in ('JEAST', 'MKV004', 'NWTN01')
and YEAR(deduction_timestamp) = ISNULL(2016, YEAR(deduction_timestamp))
and MONTH(deduction_timestamp) = ISNULL(10, MONTH(deduction_timestamp))
GROUP BY DATEPART(day,deduction_timestamp)
```